# Docker Build Failed "chmod: cannot access '/main.sh': No such file or directory"

Tags: shell, docker, build, dockerfile

[this is the error I'm getting after build command ]

```
Step 7/9 : RUN chmod +x /main.sh
 ---> Running in 6e880a009c7d

chmod: cannot access '/main.sh': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x /main.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

and here is my docker file

```
FROM centos:latest

MAINTAINER Aditya Gupta

#install git 

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install git

#make git repo folder, change GIT_LOCATION
RUN mkdir -p /home/centos/doimages/dockimg;cd /home/centos/doimages/dockimg;
RUN git clone https://(username):(password)@gitlab.com/abc/xyz.git (foldername);cd (foldername)/


Run chmod +x ./main.sh

 RUN echo " ./main.sh\n "

 EXPOSE Portnumber
```

Answer (score 1):

When you perform a RUN step in a Dockerfile, a temporary container is launched, often with a shell parsing your command. When that command finishes, the container exits, and docker packages the filesystem changes as an image layer. That process is repeated from the beginning for each RUN line.

The key piece there is the shell exits, losing environment variables you've set, background processes you've run, and in this case, the current working directory you tried to set here:

```
RUN git clone https://(username):(password)@gitlab.com/abc/xyz.git (foldername);cd (foldername)/
```

Instead of a `cd` in a RUN command, you can update the value of WORKDIR:

```
RUN git clone https://(username):(password)@gitlab.com/abc/xyz.git (foldername)
WORKDIR foldername
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute a shell file which does not exist on your docker machine. use ADD command to add your script to your docker image!

```
-- somewehe inside your dockerfile befor the execution ---
ADD ./PATH/ON/HOST/main.sh /PATH/YOU/LIKE/ON/DOCKER/MACHINE
```

Then try to build your docker machine

Comment: i have clone a repo  from gitlab inside gitlab shell file is there. i want to give +x permission to execute it .in chmod command there is error

Comment: as I said before that, you should add to it your machine!. 
With current docker file, it is like you are giving a Permission to a file which does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

issue is resolved with workdir and cloning manually without docker file and then give the path to mainsh in dockerfile.